# Laravel 5.4 testing with Mail::fake - how to access message body?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm running Laravel 5.4 and testing Mailables with Mail::fake() and Mail::assertSent(). There are assertions for things like hasTo($email) and hasCc($email), but there doesn't seem to be a way to access the message contents. I would like to test that the email body contains a particular string.

Pseudocode:

```
Mail::assertSent(UserInvited::class, function($mail) use($token) {
    return $mail->bodyContains($token); # that method does not really exist
});
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Do you find a solution?

Answer (score 14):

Having run into the same situation and not having any luck with searches - after debugging:

```
Mail::assertSent(InstanceOfMailableEmail::class, function($mail) use ($needle) {

    // now your email has properties set
    $mail->build(); 

    //check the content body for a string
    return strpos($mail->viewData['content'], $needle) !== false;
});
```

Comment: Is content an attribute of the mailable class?

Comment: `viewData` is, and it is an array; `content` is one of the keys on that array; there's some magic happening in `buildViewData` which would indicate that `content` should be attribute of `Mailable` (as it's populating `viewData` from reflection of this), but I don't remember why I couldn't use it. Maybe it's protected, I don't remember (it was some time ago ;))

Comment: I am using Laravel 5.6 and it seems that `$mail->viewData` is empty after calling build

Comment: This is a pretty bad solution because you are making assertions about the source/original variables, not the rendered email. Maybe your rendered email won't have any of that

Comment: @DenisMysenko would be happy to use `$mail->getContent()` if it existed, without this workaround. If you have ideas how to accomplish such assertion, please post!

Answer (score 1):

There's a package that you can pull in for testing mail. But as of right now, you have to be a little creative with getting it to work because they haven't specified Laravel 5.4.* in the reqs. So, go into your `composer.json` file and build your own package from this repo with the updated requirement for Laravel 5.4.* like this:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "package",
        "package": {
            "name": "spinen/laravel-mail-assertions",
            "version": "0.1.2",
            "require": {
                "php": ">=5.5.0",
                "illuminate/support": "~5.1.10|5.2.*|5.3.*|5.4.*",
                "swiftmailer/swiftmailer": "~5.1"
            },
            "require-dev": {
                "mockery/mockery": "^0.9.1",
                "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0|~5.0",
                "psy/psysh": "^0.5.1",
                "satooshi/php-coveralls": "^0.6.1",
                "symfony/var-dumper": "~2.7|~3.0"
            },
            "autoload": {
                "psr-4": {
                    "Spinen\\MailAssertions\\": "src"
                }
            },
            "autoload-dev": {
                "psr-4": {
                    "Spinen\\MailAssertions\\": "tests"
                }
            },
            "config": {
                "preferred-install": "dist"
            },
            "dist": {
                "url": "https://github.com/spinen/laravel-mail-assertions/archive/0.1.1.zip",
                "type": "zip"
            }
        }
    }
],
```

Then, under `require-dev`, add your custom package:

```
"require-dev": {
    "spinen/laravel-mail-assertions": "^0.1.2"
},
```

Once you have that installed, set `MAIL_DRIVER=log` in your `.env` file and pull the `Spinen\MailAssertions\MailTracking` trait into your tests. This trait has methods like `seeEmailContains`, `seeEmailSubjectContains`, etc. to assert that text exists in any emails that were sent.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I do it (along with helpful hints about how to do other stuff too):

```
Mail::fake(); //https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/mocking#mail-fake
$firstName = 'Sally';    
$self = $this;
Mail::assertQueued(MyMailable::class, function($mail) use($self, $firstName) {
    $mail->build(); // to set the email properties            
    $self->assertEquals($firstName, $mail->viewData["firstName"]);
    $self->assertEquals(["X-SES-CONFIGURATION-SET" => config('services.ses.options.ConfigurationSetName')], $mail->getHeaders());
    $self->assertTrue($mail->hasBcc(config('mail.supportTeam.address'), config('mail.supportTeam.name')));
    return true;
});
```

Comment: In Laravel 5.6 `$mail->viewData` is empty. Does it only work from 5.7 onwards? And `viewData` is only to access attributes of the mailable, right? It does not help to get the rendered content of the mailable?

Comment: @Adam I'm not familiar with 5.6, and since this was more than a year ago, I'm not sure of the details of 5.7+ either. I see other answers mention `$mail->viewData` too.

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue on GitHub asking for this: https://github.com/laravel/ideas/issues/405

It seems that Taylor closed this request without comment.

If you want to check if a string is in the rendered mail, you could to without mocking the Mail facade. Just do this:

```
$mail  = new Mailable(...);
$html  = $mail->render();
$found = (strpos($html, 'Hello') !== false);
```

Answer (score 1):

The trick with preserving the original mail manager before creating a fake can do the trick. Once you are ready to run the assertions of `Mailable`, restore the original MM.

Example:

```php
    public function testInvite(): void
    {
        $mailerOriginal = Mail::getFacadeRoot();
        static::assertTrue(\assert($mailerOriginal instanceof MailManager));
        Mail::fake();

        // --- Your test logic. --- 

        // Note that the callback will be called as many times as there
        // were emails sent (of the given type).
        Mail::assertSent(DocumentShareAccess::class, function (DocumentShareAccess $mail) use ($mailerOriginal): bool {
            // The fake has no rendering capability, so have to swap back.
            Mail::swap($mailerOriginal);

            $mail->assertSeeInHtml('contact the document owner');
            static::assertTrue($mail->hasTo($invitee->email), $invitee->email);

            return true;
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This way we can render body even in 5.4:

```
Mail::assertSent($mailable, function ($mail) use ($needle) {
    $m = $mail->build();
    $body = view($m->view, $m->viewData)->render();

    return strpos($body, $needle) !== false;
});
```

From [https://github.com/laravel/ideas/issues/405#issuecomment-412427637](https://github.com/laravel/ideas/issues/405)